# How to apply table/view from a database outside of that defined in a connection manager

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and was recently asked to update the TSQL query defining an OLE DB Source results.  This OLE DB Source is defining a database called Common.  But recently I was asked to include in the same TSQL a join to a table in another database called Sales.  Both Common and Sales databases are located on the same server.  The problem I have is that since Sales is not defined in the connection string, an error appears stating "Invalid object name 'Sales.dbo.SalesTable."  Even with the call to the Sales table fully qualified in the TSQL join, it still fails.

Unfortunately, creating a view in the Common database to pull information from Sales and then applying that view in the TSQL is not an option.  Is there another way to work around this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a synonym in your "Common" database that points to the SalesTable. From that point forward, you just interact with the synonym.

Also, you don't define sales in your connection string.  You connect to your Common database on the server and execute queries against that. If one of those queries happens to pull in data from another database, on the same server, it's not a big deal.

Can you provide any examples?

Comment: The DBA and system architect do not like synonyms, but I agree with your recommendation being the best approach.  Thanks!